# Is there a way to tell the compiler that nobody will implement a trait for a reference to a generic type?

Tags: rust

Here is toy code that demonstrates the problem:

```
trait Foo {}

trait Boo<T> {
    fn f() -> T;
}

impl<T> Boo<T> for i32
where
    T: Foo,
{
    fn f() -> T {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Boo<&'a T> for i32
where
    T: Foo,
{
    fn f() -> T {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

I want to have two generic implementations of `trait Boo`, but it doesn't compile:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Boo<&_>` for type `i32`:
  --> src/main.rs:16:1
   |
7  | / impl<T> Boo<T> for i32
8  | | where
9  | |     T: Foo,
10 | | {
...  |
13 | |     }
14 | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
15 | 
16 | / impl<'a, T> Boo<&'a T> for i32
17 | | where
18 | |     T: Foo,
19 | | {
...  |
22 | |     }
23 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `i32`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `Foo` for type `&_`
```

I do not plan to make this part of functionality to other crates. I tried:

- moving this code to binary crate that obviously can not be used from other crates
- moving this to a private `mod`
- marking the trait as `pub(crate)`

all with no success.

Is there anyway to give the compiler a hint that it should not care that anybody will implement `Foo` for any reference?

Maybe my toy example is not the best, so here is the real code.
It's used for integration with the C part of my program, so it's a little
complicated.

```
impl<T: MyTrait> MyFrom<Option<T>> for *mut c_void {
    fn my_from(x: Option<T>) -> Self {
        match x {
            Some(x) => <T>::alloc_heap_for(x),
            None => ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyFrom<Option<&'a T>> for *mut c_void {
    fn my_from(x: Option<&'a T>) -> Self {
        match x {
            Some(x) => x as *const T as *mut c_void,
            None => ptr::null_mut(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Rust issue #48869](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48869)

Answer (score 1):

The conflict here doesn't have anything to do with the reference-ness of the latter implementation. The issue is that, in the first implementation, `T` can be *any* type, including reference types. Suppose you make the following function call:

```rust
let x: i32 = 10;
let result: &u8 = x.f();
```

At this point, the type resolver needs to figure out what function is being called. It finds a conflicting implementation:

```
impl Boo<&u8> for i32 via Boo<T>  (T == &u8),
impl Boo<&u8> for i32 via Boo<&T> (T == u8),
```

You'd have exactly the same issue if you used a concrete type in the latter implementation:

```rust
// This will fail to compile
impl<T> Boo<T> for i32 { ... }
impl Boo<String> for i32 { ... }
```

This conflict means that the compiler can't allow these two implementations to coexist.

---

The specific thing you're looking to do here is called "specialization"; it refers to a proposal for a set of rules that says that overlapping implementations like this are allowed to exist *if* one of them is unambiguously more "specific" than the other, in which case the compiler will pick the more specific implementation. This is tracked as [RFC #1210](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md).