# Private trait and E0119?

Tags: rust

Is Rust has thing like "private trait"?
I mean trait defined without `pub` keyword is private?

Code bellow gives compilation error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `MyFrom<i64>` for type `std::option::Option<&_>`:
  --> src/main.rs:22:1
   |
16 | impl<T: Foo> MyFrom<i64> for Option<T> {
   | -------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
22 | impl<T: Foo> MyFrom<i64> for Option<&T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `std::option::Option<&_>`
   |
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `Foo` for type `&_`
```

But this is not public trait, and this is exe , how can " downstream crates may implement trait `Foo` for type `&_`" ? It is impossible to import trait from exe crate, and even if possible this is not `pub` trait,
so `rustc` doesn't support private traits?

```
fn main() {
    trait MyFrom<T> {
        fn my_from(_: T) -> Self;
    }

    trait Foo {}

    impl<T: Foo> MyFrom<i64> for Option<T> {
        fn my_from(x: i64) -> Self {
            unimplemented!();
        }
    }

    impl<T: Foo> MyFrom<i64> for Option<&T> {
        fn my_from(x: i64) -> Self {
            unimplemented!();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The note about downstream creates isn't the error. The error is that you have a blanket implementation for all `Option<T>` where T might be a reference type. If there was a type `T` such that `T: Foo` and `&T: Foo` then there's no way to decide which function to use for `Option<&T>::my_from`.

Comment: @turbulencetoo I understand that, but as you see my crate have no such thing: type `X` that `X: Foo + &X: Foo`, and because of `trait Foo` impossible to use outside crate, that it is not clear why compiler emit error.

Comment: Here's an even more simple example that is very similar to yours: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e75a40b5f8ef053cd7fbc5942c8ce05d It is a conflict because a `T` _could_ implement both `Foo` and `Bar`. Just because there isn't currently have such a type doesn't mean that this isn't a footgun.

Comment: @turbulencetoo But this compiler can check all crate, and it found such issue then emit error, why it emit error before I do anything wrong, there is no error in my code, it may be in the future, but when it appear then it should emit error.

Comment: @turbulencetoo If `trait` will be public, then error clear, it is impossible to control all crates that use my crate, but `trait` private, so why complain about `trait` usage before real error?

Comment: @user1244932 please check the error back it is not a root cause it is a note that if everything is right then this note may cause this error.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Sorry, I don't understand you completly. I have compilation error about possible error in the future. I can not understand why I should care about future instead of present.

Comment: @user1244932 Please remove `Foo` boundary from both implementation then you'll have same compiler error without the note. But i don't understand why did you ask this question in different shape, you should already have the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012745/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-compiler-that-nobody-will-implement-a-trait-for-a-ref)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to tell the compiler that nobody will implement a trait for a reference to a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012745/is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-compiler-that-nobody-will-implement-a-trait-for-a-ref)